# How to increase stack size on Android Gingerbread version?

Tags: android, stack-overflow

I have developing app for multiple android versions. My app ran on eclipse and working properly I moved project from eclipse to Android Studio getting stack overflow error. Programatically created child view inside the view group working fine but got some alignment issues And i want to achieve this with xml my UI design having five more background even i used visibility gone for three layout again got an same statckoverflow error.

I'm getting **java.lang.StackOverflowError** when my view hierarchy is being drawn:

```
02-05 16:46:40.449 1114-1114/com.example.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:261)
at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.remove(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:370)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(ViewTreeObserver.java:377)
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:3998)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6986)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1417)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(Unknown Source)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1871)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1524)
at android.view.ViewRoot.per
```

When i run same code on android 4.0.1 or above version it runs effectively and correct but not on android 2.3.7 below version. Please let me know if any one know about this issue ??

Comment: You have infinite loop there. Increasing stack size will not help you.

Comment: Is there any solution to achieve this?

Comment: You have to fix code that is going into loop.

Comment: post your code which cause this and then we can help you :)